# trigger_rule.TriggerRule utils airflow

Tags: airflow

I have a question and I haven't found any information about it.

What is the difference between using 'airflow.utils.trigger_rule' or just declaring the trigger_rule with string, I leave the two examples.

Apparently airflow.utils.trigger_rule has other utilities but I don't understand them yet

```
           delete_bq_table = bash_operator.BashOperator(
            task_id='delete_bq_table',
            bash_command='bq rm -f %s' % bq_dataset_name + '.' +inst_dag_id,
            trigger_rule=trigger_rule.TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
        )
```

and

```
           delete_bq_table = bash_operator.BashOperator(
            task_id='delete_bq_table',
            bash_command='bq rm -f %s' % bq_dataset_name + '.' +inst_dag_id,
            trigger_rule='all_done'
        )
```

Comment: If solved please accept answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. You can use whichever option you like.
Personally I prefer to use:

```
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
```

and then `TriggerRule.ALL_DONE` just because it avoids syntax mistakes since it provides autocomplete in the IDE.

Airflow is in the process of converting the [TriggerRule class](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/0ebd6428e6b484790bfbbe1b8687ef4e6cae10e9/airflow/utils/trigger_rule.py#L22-L35) to inherit from Enum (see [Github issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19905))